# Formulation for data insight

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, supply-chain, local-search, data

There is an interesting data insight question that I want to solve using mathematical programming. I aim to find the combination of features that has the highest impact on the target indicators.

We have collected N samples, each sample having F features (F1, F2, F3, etc.) and two indicators, I1 and I2. For example, if each sample represents a sales data, the features can be seller ID, seller's shipping city, buyer's delivery city, purchase time, shipping method, etc. The target indicator set consists of the total number of orders and the number of orders with negative reviews.

From these samples, we want to analyze and determine the minimal combination of features that results in the highest proportion of orders with negative reviews.  The combinations that offer a finer level of granularity is prefer, which may provide more insight .

For instance, if the identified feature combination is (seller's shipping city, buyer's delivery city, shipping method), it might indicate that the service quality for that shipping method in those cities is poor.

I am looking to solve this problem using mathematical programming or tree search, but I don't have a clear approach. Tree search would require exhaustive traversal, leading to a high level of complexity.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with proportion of orders with negative reviews? Can you elaborate a bit more on the problem, maybe giving an example?

Comment: If you are looking for the combination of specific feature values (e.g., shipping city = A, delivery city = B, shipping method = C) with highest proportion of negative reviews, you can just enumerate all combinations and pick a winner.

Comment: @prubin Right, we can try to enumerate all possible feature combinations, but for problems with more than 20 features, the number of all combinations could be close to a million. On the other hand, perhaps the majority of negative reviews for orders with seller shipping city=A, buyer receiving city=B, and shipping method=C are concentrated on seller id=D. How do we decide whether it is combination (A, B, C) or combination (A, B, C, D) that can provide more insight into the problem, as the latter may offer a finer level of granularity?

Comment: @PeterD  It means to provide a more detailed or specific level of combination or grouping. It refers to the idea of finding the smallest granularity of combinations to help identify problems and make targeted improvements.